# Azure media services and Flash video player

Tags: flash, azure, media

Where I can see sample of playing video uploaded to Windows Azure by Flash player with playback?

Answer (score 2):

We recently release Azure Media Player (http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/15/announcing-azure-media-player/).

The demo site is located at http://aka.ms/azuremediaplayer.

The player automatically picks the right tech (flash, silverlight or html5) and best format from Azure Media Services automatically. If you want to specifically try Flash you can go advanced options in demo and choose it. This can also be done via docs - http://aka.ms/ampdocs.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure portal:

1. open up Media services from right menu (create new service first)
2. click on Content in upper menu
3. upload video from your local (click Upload in footer menu)
4. select uploaded video from list and click Encode
5. select 'Playback on PC/Mac (via Flash/Silverlight)' from dropdown
6. when encoding is finished, select the encoded file and click Play

Edit:

1. in step 5 select 'Playback via HTML5 (IE/Chrome/Safari)'
2. after encode is finished select the asset and click Publish (footer menu)
3. copy/paste Publish Url property column value to src=""

   ```
   <video width="500" height="300" controls autoplay="false">
        <source src="">
   </video>
   ```

Comment: I mean play outside of Azure. Play video on my site, using <video> html5 tag or using Flash player. I have not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sampler player is  [here](http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/)

To implement it in your application,

Option 1) Your own Player:
For this you can go with platform specific URL+Player as mentioned  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135231/azure-media-services-player) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981284/streaming-with-azure-media-services/27448363#27448363).

Option 2) Use [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/partners/azure/)

Option3) AMS is Rolling out [new player](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223283.aspx) - Lets wait for that.