# Streaming with Azure media services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I have a media services account with a streaming unit and I have been able to upload a video and  dynamically package into various streams. I am trying to have a webpage with the streaming url to be able to serve cross platform iOS, android, desktop etc.. How do I go about it.

PS: I was able to create a page with videojs and progressive download. I am tring to explore the other option with Windows Azure.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Media Services has shipped Azure Media Player which could automatically detect the capability of your browser or device, and request the appropriate streaming format- for instance, it will grab MPEG-DASH stream with EME enabled browser, or HLS for iOS devices. You could give it a try: http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/azuremediaplayer.html. Please contact yanmf@microsoft if you want to get into Private Preview for this player. It will be free for use when we launch very soon.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JW Player](http://www.jwplayer.com/) and the Microsoft Media Platform [Player Framework](https://playerframework.codeplex.com/).  Both offer plenty of playback options for progressive and adaptive streaming to a wide range of browsers and devices.

Comment: Adding to Chris' point - you need to make sure you use the right video source URL to access the adaptive dynamic streaming capabilities. See "Streaming your content to clients" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj889436.aspx

Comment: Thanks for giving direction. JWPlayer seems paid and Microsoft Media Platform Player Framework seem restricted to windows devices. How about streaming to mobile devices including android, ios devices through HLS?

Answer (score 1):

For desktop : Use OSMF plugin - Adobe + Smooth streaming URL

For iOS : Use HTML5 Video tag+HLS v3 URL

For Android : Use HTML5 Video Tag+HLS v3 URL or Dash.JS with Mpegh Dash URL

For Windows Phone : Use Dash.js + Dash.JS URL

Hope this helps...

**Update1**:
Azure has came up with their own Media player for streaming which will take care of playing video in all the devices.

For Demo and Test - http://www.aka.ms/azuremediaplayer

For Documentaion - http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/15/announcing-azure-media-player/

Comment: Just to add for Android.. I have had better success with playing MPEG Dash streaming URL than the HLS streams.. Have had various issues with video not displaying with HLS..

Answer (score 0):

The bitdash MPEG-DASH player works also out of the box for MPEG-DASH content, here you can see an example stream comming from Azure: http://www.dash-player.com/demo/streaming-server-encoder-support/?mpd=http%3A%2F%2Fsamplescdn.origin.mediaservices.windows.net%2Fe0e820ec-f6a2-4ea2-afe3-1eed4e06ab2c%2FAzureMediaServices_Overview.ism%2Fmanifest(format%3Dmpd-time-csf)&m3u8=undefined&autoplay=true&muted=false&usePoster=true